# How do I adjust TD styles in a table with only a table ID, no TD id

Tags: html, css, html-table

[image]
Hello, I'm having to adjust a platform I work with because my boss has sold something to a new client that our platform doesn't exactly do. (I'm sure you can relate).

Good news is I've almost managed it, the only thing left is I need to adjust the 's in this table generated by our platform. The platform handily identifies the table (`id="qq_55aa3d6c69b0eb11a746dc204a5dbb30_table"`) but not the td's within it. I'd need to adjust the width's of each TD, with the first being different to the last four.

How would I go about referencing without an ID? (as in the past I've used `<td id='x'>` when creating my own tables, but I have no control over the writing of this table).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: querySelectorAll

Comment: Hard to tell exactly with your picture instead of real code but it appears those table id's in the table 'td' all have the same really long id - duplicate id's in a document are invalid.

Comment: Please post actual code and the CSS you have attempted here.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss those are sub tables with the <TD>'s, I'm looking at adjust <td style="width:120px;height:40px"> and  <td style="width:190px;height:40px"> not the tables within them (or platform really does seem to like nestling tables).
I was hoping to do something with nth-child but I can only see that to apply as CSS rather than adjusting the td style command.

Comment: To clarify, create a properly asked question with what you have tried, what challenge you have and what your desired result is.  Put your actual code IN your question including the CSS you have tried. reference https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, found a little JS that can do it:

```
var tr = document.getElementById("qq_55aa3d6c69b0eb11a746dc204a5dbb30_table");
var tds = tr.getElementsByTagName("td");

tds[0].style.width="120px";
for(var i = 1; i < tds.length; i++) {
   tds[i].style.width="190px";
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wefc8rna/1/